# Vagrant: не заливается дамп базы

Tags: mysql, virtualbox, vagrant, ansible, xubuntu

Вот такая ошибка в конце vagrant up --provision --debug. Не работает только у меня, на других машинах все ок.
Окружение: последние версии xubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, ansible.

DEBUG subprocess: stdout: failed: [default] => (item={'invocation': {'module_name': u'stat', u'module_args': {u'checksum_algorithm': u'sha1', u'get_md5': True, u'follow': False, u'get_checksum': True, u'path': u'/vagrant/my_project/dump.sql'}}, 'item': {u'virtualhost': {u'root': u'/vagrant/my_project', u'name': u'shop.instoit.local'}, u'config': {u'dest': u'/vagrant/my_project/apps/config/config.ini', u'src': u'/vagrant/my_project/apps/config/config.sample.ini'}, u'database': u'shop'}, u'stat': {u'uid': 777, u'exists': True, u'woth': True, u'mtime': 1459422099.0, u'inode': 8785711, u'isgid': False, u'size': 62333675, u'roth': True, u'isuid': False, u'isreg': True, u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True, u'xoth': True, u'islnk': False, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'rgrp': True, u'path': u'/vagrant/my_project/dump.sql', u'xusr': True, u'atime': 1460829940.8107455, u'md5': u'5e30e503bd8299ae510894ded5486674', u'isdir': False, u'ctime': 1460723296.6047752, u'isblk': False, u'xgrp': True, u'dev': 25, u'wgrp': True, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0777', u'checksum': u'cfd8f723aac16e9cf830d28a5d13ebd6c26f3755', u'rusr': True}, u'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"_ansible_no_log": false, "changed": false, "invocation": {"module_args": {"checksum_algorithm": "sha1", "follow": false, "get_checksum": true, "get_md5": true, "path": "/vagrant/my_project/dump.sql"}, "module_name": "stat"}, "item": {"config": {"dest": "/vagrant/my_project/apps/config/config.ini", "src": "/vagrant/my_project/apps/config/config.sample.ini"}, "database": "shop", "virtualhost": {"name": "myproject.local", "root": "/vagrant/my_project"}}, "stat": {"atime": 1460829940.8107455, "checksum": "cfd8f723aac16e9cf830d28a5d13ebd6c26f3755", "ctime": 1460723296.6047752, "dev": 25, "exists": true, "gid": 0, "inode": 8785711, "isblk": false, "ischr": false, "isdir": false, "isfifo": false, "isgid": false, "islnk": false, "isreg": true, "issock": false, "isuid": false, "md5": "5e30e503bd8299ae510894ded5486674", "mode": "0777", "mtime": 1459422099.0, "nlink": 1, "path": "/vagrant/my_project/dump.sql", "rgrp": true, "roth": true, "rusr": true, "size": 62333675, "uid": 777, "wgrp": true, "woth": true, "wusr": true, "xgrp": true, "xoth": true, "xusr": true}}, "msg": "ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 698528: Lost connection to MySQL server during query\n"}
 INFO interface: info: failed: [default] => (item={'invocation': {'module_name': u'stat', u'module_args': {u'checksum_algorithm': u'sha1', u'get_md5': True, u'follow': False, u'get_checksum': True, u'path': u'/vagrant/my_project/dump.sql'}}, 'item': {u'virtualhost': {u'root': u'/vagrant/my_project', u'name': u'myproject.local'}, u'config': {u'dest': u'/vagrant/my_project/apps/config/config.ini', u'src': u'/vagrant/my_project/apps/config/config.sample.ini'}, u'database': u'shop'}, u'stat': {u'uid': 777, u'exists': True, u'woth': True, u'mtime': 1459422099.0, u'inode': 8785711, u'isgid': False, u'size': 62333675, u'roth': True, u'isuid': False, u'isreg': True, u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True, u'xoth': True, u'islnk': False, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'rgrp': True, u'path': u'/vagrant/my_project/dump.sql', u'xusr': True, u'atime': 1460829940.8107455, u'md5': u'5e30e503bd8299ae510894ded5486674', u'isdir': False, u'ctime': 1460723296.6047752, u'isblk': False, u'xgrp': True, u'dev': 25, u'wgrp': True, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0777', u'checksum': u'cfd8f723aac16e9cf830d28a5d13ebd6c26f3755', u'rusr': True}, u'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"_ansible_no_log": false, "changed": false, "invocation": {"module_args": {"checksum_algorithm": "sha1", "follow": false, "get_checksum": true, "get_md5": true, "path": "/vagrant/my_project/dump.sql"}, "module_name": "stat"}, "item": {"config": {"dest": "/vagrant/my_project/apps/config/config.ini", "src": "/vagrant/my_project/apps/config/config.sample.ini"}, "database": "shop", "virtualhost": {"name": "myproject.local", "root": "/vagrant/my_project"}}, "stat": {"atime": 1460829940.8107455, "checksum": "cfd8f723aac16e9cf830d28a5d13ebd6c26f3755", "ctime": 1460723296.6047752, "dev": 25, "exists": true, "gid": 0, "inode": 8785711, "isblk": false, "ischr": false, "isdir": false, "isfifo": false, "isgid": false, "islnk": false, "isreg": true, "issock": false, "isuid": false, "md5": "5e30e503bd8299ae510894ded5486674", "mode": "0777", "mtime": 1459422099.0, "nlink": 1, "path": "/vagrant/my_project/dump.sql", "rgrp": true, "roth": true, "rusr": true, "size": 62333675, "uid": 777, "wgrp": true, "woth": true, "wusr": true, "xgrp": true, "xoth": true, "xusr": true}}, "msg": "ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 698528: Lost connection to MySQL server during query\n"}

failed: [default] => (item={'invocation': {'module_name': u'stat', u'module_args': {u'checksum_algorithm': u'sha1', u'get_md5': True, u'follow': False, u'get_checksum': True, u'path': u'/vagrant/my_project/dump.sql'}}, 'item': {u'virtualhost': {u'root': u'/vagrant/my_project', u'name': u'myproject.local'}, u'config': {u'dest': u'/vagrant/my_project/apps/config/config.ini', u'src': u'/vagrant/my_project/apps/config/config.sample.ini'}, u'database': u'shop'}, u'stat': {u'uid': 777, u'exists': True, u'woth': True, u'mtime': 1459422099.0, u'inode': 8785711, u'isgid': False, u'size': 62333675, u'roth': True, u'isuid': False, u'isreg': True, u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True, u'xoth': True, u'islnk': False, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'rgrp': True, u'path': u'/vagrant/my_project/dump.sql', u'xusr': True, u'atime': 1460829940.8107455, u'md5': u'5e30e503bd8299ae510894ded5486674', u'isdir': False, u'ctime': 1460723296.6047752, u'isblk': False, u'xgrp': True, u'dev': 25, u'wgrp': True, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0777', u'checksum': u'cfd8f723aac16e9cf830d28a5d13ebd6c26f3755', u'rusr': True}, u'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"_ansible_no_log": false, "changed": false, "invocation": {"module_args": {"checksum_algorithm": "sha1", "follow": false, "get_checksum": true, "get_md5": true, "path": "/vagrant/my_project/dump.sql"}, "module_name": "stat"}, "item": {"config": {"dest": "/vagrant/my_project/apps/config/config.ini", "src": "/vagrant/my_project/apps/config/config.sample.ini"}, "database": "shop", "virtualhost": {"name": "myproject.local", "root": "/vagrant/my_project"}}, "stat": {"atime": 1460829940.8107455, "checksum": "cfd8f723aac16e9cf830d28a5d13ebd6c26f3755", "ctime": 1460723296.6047752, "dev": 25, "exists": true, "gid": 0, "inode": 8785711, "isblk": false, "ischr": false, "isdir": false, "isfifo": false, "isgid": false, "islnk": false, "isreg": true, "issock": false, "isuid": false, "md5": "5e30e503bd8299ae510894ded5486674", "mode": "0777", "mtime": 1459422099.0, "nlink": 1, "path": "/vagrant/my_project/dump.sql", "rgrp": true, "roth": true, "rusr": true, "size": 62333675, "uid": 777, "wgrp": true, "woth": true, "wusr": true, "xgrp": true, "xoth": true, "xusr": true}}, "msg": "ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 698528: Lost connection to MySQL server during query\n"}
........

DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 31575
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 2
ERROR warden: Error occurred: Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.

...
 INFO interface: error: Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
 INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Vagrant::Errors::AnsibleFailed", "Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be\nvisible above. Please fix these errors and try again."]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас MySQL судя по всему не успевает обработать дамп, и закрывает соединение по таймауту. Проверьте точно ли у вас совпадают настройки в my.cnf с соседними машинами, возможно помимо provision-настроек, используются дополнительные (больший таймаут, размер буферов).

Для того, чтобы побороть ошибку, нужно ускорить развертывание, отключить мешающие факторы (запись транзакций сразу на жесткий диск, индексирование, по возможности вставлять данные многострочными INSERT-запросами). Для того, чтобы дать более конкретные рекомендации, нужно смотреть на ваш my.cnf файл и структуру дампа.

Как вариант, для начала хорошо бы сформировать урезанную версию MySQL-дампа (с меньшим количеством данных) и развернуть ее.